# How to start using tensorflow-lite in a gradle-Project?

Tags: java, tensorflow, gradle, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to import tensorflow-lite to my Java - Gradle Project but when I import the dependency IntelliJ tells me: "Unable to resolve org.tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly"
How can I import tensorflow-lite to this simple Project?

this is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:0.0.0-nightly'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using maven repository as reference you should put your graddle reference like this

```java
compile group: 'org.tensorflow', name: 'tensorflow-lite', version: '0.0.0-nightly'
```

reference:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tensorflow/tensorflow-lite/0.0.0-nightly

You really wanna use the nightly version? This version is unstable like a "beta version"